# How to change child state from another child without re-rendering parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to change the content of a child component in response to a user event in another child component without causing the parent to re-render.

I've tried storing the child state setter to a variable in the parent but it is not defined by the time the children have all rendered, so it doesn't work.

Is there a minimal way to accomplish this (without installing a state management library)?

ChildToChild.tsx

```
import React, {
  Dispatch,
  SetStateAction,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useState,
} from "react";

export default function ChildToChild() {
  const renderCounter = useRef(0);
  renderCounter.current = renderCounter.current + 1;

  let setChildOneContent;
  const childOneContentController = (
    setter: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>
  ) => {
    setChildOneContent = setter;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Don't re-render me please</h1>
      <p>No. Renders: {renderCounter.current}</p>
      <ChildOne childOneContentController={childOneContentController} />
      <ChildTwo setChildOneContent={setChildOneContent} />
    </div>
  );
}

function ChildOne({
  childOneContentController,
}: {
  childOneContentController: (setter: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>) => void;
}) {
  const [content, setContent] = useState("original content");

  useEffect(() => {
    childOneContentController(setContent);
  }, [childOneContentController, setContent]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Child One</h2>
      <p>{content}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

function ChildTwo({
  setChildOneContent,
}: {
  setChildOneContent: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>> | undefined;
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Child Two</h2>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          if (setChildOneContent) setChildOneContent("content changed");
        }}
      >
        Change Child One Content
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what about redux?

Comment: @k-wasilewski Is it really necessary to install a 168kB 3rd party library to solve this? The question states "without installing a state management library".

Comment: Either 1. use a React context. You can set and consume state from anywhere under the provider. Or, 2. raise the state in to the parent like you are doing (but with a useSate). This will cause parent to rerender, but if it's written properly that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @windowsill Neither accomplishes the goal of not re-rendering the parent.

Comment: It's not a problem to re-render your parent if you use `React.memo` on the child(ren) that you don't want to re-render every time. I won't go as far as to say that your requirements call for an anti-pattern solution, but they certainly don't allow for an idiomatic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an one-off, you could use the following (another `ref` to store & use the `ChildOne` `setContent`:

```
import React, {
  Dispatch,
  SetStateAction,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useState
} from "react";

function ChildOne({
  setChildOneRef
}: {
  setChildOneRef: React.MutableRefObject<React.Dispatch<
    React.SetStateAction<string>
  > | null>;
}) {
  const [content, setContent] = useState("original content");

  useEffect(() => {
    setChildOneRef.current = setContent;
  }, [setChildOneRef]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Child One</h2>
      <p>{content}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

function ChildTwo({
  setChildOneRef
}: {
  setChildOneRef: React.MutableRefObject<React.Dispatch<
    React.SetStateAction<string>
  > | null>;
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Child Two</h2>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setChildOneRef.current?.("content changed");
        }}
      >
        Change Child One Content
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export function ChildToChild() {
  const renderCounter = useRef(0);
  renderCounter.current = renderCounter.current + 1;

  const setChildOneRef = useRef<Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>> | null>(null);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Don't re-render me please</h1>
      <p>No. Renders: {renderCounter.current}</p>
      <ChildOne setChildOneRef={setChildOneRef} />
      <ChildTwo setChildOneRef={setChildOneRef} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

If this pattern is common in your code, you may still want to use state management library or evaluate if "childs" should be really separated.

Comment: The child component loses control of itself by passing reference of the useState setter to the outside. The solution with RxJS Subject means that child component is only notified that should do something.

Comment: This is a race condition and an antipattern. There are several idiomatic solutions: raised state (with memo to control how the parent renders), redux, react context, render pattern, probably others.

Comment: @windowsill how do you use redux, react context without re-render parent??

Comment: @famfamfam you wrap the parent in `React.memo` and consume the context in the children like `const context = useContext(myContext)`.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to achieve by

1. Using state in child components
2. Using a callback function in the parent component that calls the `setState` function of the child component. This will trigger re-render of the child but not of itself (parent).

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/child-re-rendering-only-x37ol

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object, store the hook on that object, and use the hook from the object on the children. Not sure why the output count increments twice...

```
import { useState } from "react";

let parentRenderCount = 0;
let child1RenderCount = 0;
let child2RenderCount = 0;

const Child1 = ( { stateHolder } ) => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState( 0 )
    console.log('child1 render', ++child1RenderCount)
    stateHolder.count = count
    stateHolder.setCount = setCount
    return <div>
        {count}
    </div>
}

const Child2 = ( { stateHolder } ) => {
    console.log('child2 render', ++child2RenderCount)
    return <button onClick={() => stateHolder.setCount( stateHolder.count + 1 )}>
        clickme
    </button>
}


function App() {
    const stateHolder = { }
    console.log('parent render', ++parentRenderCount)
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Child1 stateHolder={stateHolder} />
            <Child2 stateHolder={stateHolder} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Mmm it looks like it would work, but IDK if a global is such a good idea.

Comment: Since it's a const and not exported, it's only accessible from within that file. Presumably in the real world scenario the child elements would be in separate component files and would not have access to that variable. Also, it works the same with the variable in the component declaration. Since a re-render of the parent would trigger re-renders of all the children, it would still be correct after any parent state changes, but would have a new object.

Answer (score 0):

The event could be propagated over the RxJS Subject, with value if it is needed.

```
// in parent

// const subject = new rxjs.Subject();
const subject = { // or create lightweight alternative
  nextHandlers: [],
  next: function(value) {
    this.nextHandlers.forEach(handler => handler(value));
  },
  subscribe: function(nextHandler) {
    this.nextHandlers.push(nextHandler);
    return { 
      unsubscribe: () => {
        this.nextHandlers.splice(
          this.nextHandlers.indexOf(nextHandler),
          1
        );
      }
    };
  }
};

// provide next method to the childOne
onClick={value => subject.next(value)}

// provide subscribe method to the childTwo
subscribeOnClick={(nextHandler) => subject.subscribe(nextHandler)}

// in childTwo
useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = subscribeOnClick(value => setContent(value));
  return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
}, [subscribeOnClick]);
```

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about, what is RxJS? The question was looking for a solution without a lib

Comment: Ok, then just ignore my answer. It was only inspired by foreign lib, but without a need to link it.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>` function in a `ref` in the parent:

```tsx
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {
  Dispatch,
  MutableRefObject,
  ReactElement,
  SetStateAction,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useState,
} from 'react';

type ChildProps = {
  setValueRef: MutableRefObject<Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>> | undefined>;
};

function Child1 (props: ChildProps): ReactElement {
  const [dateString, setDateString] = useState(new Date().toISOString());

  useEffect(() => {
    props.setValueRef.current = setDateString;
  }, [props.setValueRef, setDateString]);

  return <div>{dateString}</div>;
}

function Child2 (props: ChildProps): ReactElement {
  const handleClick = (): void => {
    props.setValueRef.current?.(new Date().toISOString());
  };

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Update</button>;
}

function Parent (): ReactElement {
  const setValueRef = useRef<Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>> | undefined>();
  const renderCountRef = useRef(0);
  renderCountRef.current += 1;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Render count: {renderCountRef.current}</div>
      <Child1 {...{setValueRef}} />
      <Child2 {...{setValueRef}} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here's the same code in a runnable snippet (with types erased and `import` statements converted to use the UMD version of React):

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.16.2/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="react">

const {useEffect, useRef, useState} = React;

function Child1 (props) {
  const [dateString, setDateString] = useState(new Date().toISOString());

  useEffect(() => {
    props.setValueRef.current = setDateString;
  }, [props.setValueRef, setDateString]);

  return <div>{dateString}</div>;
}

function Child2 (props) {
  const handleClick = () => {
    props.setValueRef.current?.(new Date().toISOString());
  };

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Update</button>;
}

function Parent () {
  const setValueRef = useRef();
  const renderCountRef = useRef(0);
  renderCountRef.current += 1;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Render count: {renderCountRef.current}</div>
      <Child1 {...{setValueRef}} />
      <Child2 {...{setValueRef}} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```

That being said, this is a strange pattern, and the scenario can be solved idiomatically using [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) (this is the case it's designed for).

Comment: what's the difference between this and @ejose19's approach?

Comment: I didn't look at any other answers until you asked: I'd say they're effectively the same, except I provided a way to prove it works (the snippet) in the answer. Also, see my note at the end.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I understand React.memo can prevent re-renders of children, but it can't prevent the parent from re-rendering, which is what the question is about. I think you're right though, it's more idiomatic, and in most cases it can probably suffice.

Comment: no need to dispatch, just apply forwardRef to child then update what property you want over forwardRef function